# Intent-Filter for content:// URI on Android 9 and higher

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I want to write intent-filter that will allow my app to open files with custom files exception. On Android 8 (and before) there was a possibility to do this as intent url was delivered like this (this comes from Chrome downloads screen):

```
content://com.android.chrome.FileProvider/downloads/somefile.xyz
```

Now, the same screen on Android 9+ delivers intent like this:

```
content://media/external/downloads/25
```

Is there a possibility to detect my file extension with such intent-uri format without writing an intent filter that just detects all intents (*)?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/retrieve-info this might help you

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a possibility to detect my file extension with such intent-uri format without writing an intent filter that just detects all intents (*)?

No, sorry.

> On Android 8 (and before) there was a possibility to do this as intent url was delivered like this

There is no requirement, on any version of Android, for a `content` `Uri` to contain a file extension, just as there is no requirement on the Web for an `http` or `https` URL to contain a file extension.

> this comes from Chrome downloads screen

That may be true for a particular version of Chrome. Please do not assume that Chrome will always use a file extension. And please do not assume that every Android device user uses Chrome and *only* uses Chrome. There is no requirement for other apps to use a `content` `Uri` with a file extension.